# Can't seem to figure out how to get the permissions to post to my app wall from my website with my admin token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

All I want to do is post to my facebook app wall with my website after certain actions occur on the website...used to work however at some point I started neglecting my code and it stopped working..

So now I want to get it working again however I believe I am having an issue with permissions that I can't seem to get around, as when i attempt to post from my website it is returning the error:

> *** GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I applied for the following permissions:

> manage_pages and publish_pages

But I am now told the following:

> General
>  You don't need any additional permissions to post to Pages or
>   blogs that you administer. You only need to submit your app for review
>   if your app will use a public-facing login.

So wondering if anybody can tell me the steps to submit my app for review. Not seeming to see how to do that seemingly most basic action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to submit for review, if you are the only one using the app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#roles

Comment: Thanks for the response...related follow up question here if interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096203/how-to-extend-a-facebook-token-to-not-have-an-expiration